# Django Module And Varbinary() Fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have this Django **model**:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    idlog = models.CharField(max_length=16L, db_column='idLog') # Field name made lowercase.
    idhandle = models.CharField(max_length=16L, db_column='idHandle') # Field name made lowercase.
    idprevious = models.CharField(max_length=16L, db_column='idPrevious', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    idseverity = models.IntegerField(db_column='idSeverity') # Field name made lowercase.
    iderrorcode = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='idErrorCode', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    eventdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='eventDate') # Field name made lowercase.
    trace = models.CharField(max_length=1024L, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1024L, blank=True)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=32L, blank=True)
    class_field = models.CharField(max_length=32L, db_column='class', blank=True) # Field renamed because it was a Python reserved word.
    backedup = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='backedUp', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'log'

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

idlog , idhandle and idprevious are fields of Varbinary(16) at MySQL DB table.
Each on of them holds Globally unique identifier (GUID).

At my **View** there is this simply method:

```
def logger_handle(request):

    tableSize = Handle.objects.all().__len__()
    handles = Handle.objects.all().order_by('id')[tableSize - 20:tableSize]

    context = {'handles': handles}
    return render_to_response('ate_logger/logger_handle.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

At the logger_handle.html **Template** i have this table:

```
<table width="100%" class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">idlog</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">idhandle</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">idprevious</th>
        <th style="width: 180px">eventdate</th>
        <th style="width: 50px">severity</th>
        <th style="width: 50px">errorcode</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">trace</th>
        <th style="width: 300px">message</th>
        <th style="width: 110px">method</th>
    </tr>

    {% for log in logs %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ log.idlog }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.idhandle }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.idprevious }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.eventdate }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.idseverity }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.iderrorcode }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.trace }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.message }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.method }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

My problem (as you can see in the image) is that at the idlog , idhandle and idprevious there are no values (unless it's None at the table)

[image]

At the **View** using binascii i can convert it to the normal string using command `binascii.b2a_hex(value['idhandle'])` and therefor i can see the guid.

**My question** is how can set it at the **Model** layer, how can i tell django to convert it and transfer it to the view as a string so i can show it easily at the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should create your custom field class to represent idlog, idhandle and idprevious like described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-field-data-for-serialization and put conversion code in body of value_to_string method of the custom field class.

Note: you should call count() on querysets instead of calling .**len**() because otherwise you'll have whole datase fetched and inspected to only calculate length.

Also, if you are going to inspect an object length use function len(), it calls **len**() under the hood for you.